# QC - How to export Requirements and their corresponding test cases from excel to QC in a single go?

Tags: macros, hp-quality-center

I am aware we shall do the task seperately, then again we need to link each requirement with a test case. Is there any macro or short cuts available to export Requirements and their corresponding test cases from excel to QC in a single go. Please provide

Answer (score 1):

One can retrieve the Requirements and corresponding test cases by running an excel query in QC. Below query does it  and you can export the results

For more details on how to arrive at this query refer below link
http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/how-to-retrieve-requirement-test-case.html

> Select r.rq_req_name, t.TS_NAME,ln_bug_id from TEST t, REQ r,
>   REQ_COVER rc, TESTCYCL tc, LINK l where rq_req_id = rc_req_id and
>   rc_entity_id = ts_test_id and rc_entity_type = 'TEST' and t.ts_test_id
>   = tc.tc_test_id and l.ln_entity_type = 'TESTCYCL' and Tc.TC_TESTCYCL_ID = l.ln_entity_id

Answer (score 1):

I used the following query and it works:

```
select rc.RC_REQ_ID, r.rq_req_name, rc.RC_ENTITY_ID, t.ts_name, t.ts_description, t.ts_user_01
from TEST t, REQ r, REQ_COVER rc
where rc.RC_REQ_ID = r.rq_req_id
and rc.RC_ENTITY_ID = t.ts_test_id
```